# My Express and JWT apps get inconsistent behavior with req.cookies on the hosting service

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, cookies, jwt

## req.cookies is sometimes working, sometimes not.

I'm making a simple login system in Express; I use JWT for authentication and store the token in cookies. I tried the application on localhost, and it worked perfectly, but after I deployed it on a hosting service, when I tried to log in, the cookies were generated, but I got redirected to /login since req.cookies.token did not exist. But the weird thing is, it sometimes works (I don't know why), and I assume that the token checking code is called too soon before the token could be generated.

`authMiddleware.js`

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
require("dotenv").config();
const secretKey = process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY;
const publicRoutes = ["/login"];

const authMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.cookies.token;

  if (publicRoutes.includes(req.path)) {
    return next();
  }

  if (!token) {
    return res.redirect("/login");
    // return res.status(401).json({ message: "TOKEN NOT EXIST" });
  }

  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, secretKey);
    res.locals.currentUser = decoded;
    req.currentUser = decoded;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "TOKEN INVALID" });
    // return res.redirect("/");
    // res.redirect("/login");
  }
};

module.exports = authMiddleware;
```

`loginController`

```
router.get("/login", (request, response) => {
  response.render("pages/login");
});

router.post("/login", async (request, response) => {
  const { username, password, role } = request.body;
  try {
    const query = await pool.query(
      `SELECT * FROM admin_${role} WHERE username = $1`,
      [username]
    );

    const results = query.rows[0];
    if (!results || !bcrypt.compareSync(password, results.password)) {
      return response
        .status(401)
        .json({ message: "Invalid username or password" });
    }

    const payload = {
      id: results.id,
      name: results.name,
      role: role,
    };
    const token = jwt.sign(payload, secretKey, {
      expiresIn: "1h",
    });

    // Set the token as a cookie
    response.cookie("token", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      expires: new Date(Date.now() + 86400000),
    });

    // Return the response or redirect the user
    response.redirect("/");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Login error:", error);
    return response.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
  }
});
```

`index.js`

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();
// REQUIRE ALL CONTROLLERS IS HERE

const authMiddleware = require("./middleware/authMiddleware");
const port = 3000;

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));
require("dotenv").config(); // Load .env file

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(authMiddleware);
app.use("/", homeController);
|
|
|
V
app.use(lastContoller)
```

**Here's what i've done:
**

- Try adding a delay using setTimeout. Not workied.
- not using auth middleware on index
- and others, but I forgot.
- I also search for similar problems like req.token undefined," but there is no case that I found where the problem only 'sometimes' happens.